# use string with loop for in c

Tags: c, string, loops, for-loop

with this list of value:

```
char *icon[6] = {"icon0","icon1","icon2","icon3","icon4","icon5"};

char *ICON_FILE_PATH[6] = {"host0:img/200px/power-button-off.png","host0:img/200px/gamepad-console.png","host0:img/200px/dropbox-logo.png","host0:img/200px/open-folder.png","host0:img/200px/sitemap.png","host0:img/200px/settings.png"};
```

I need to get that:

```
#define ICON_FILE_PATH1 "host0:img/200px/power-button-off.png"
#define ICON_FILE_PATH2 "host0:img/200px/gamepad-console.png"
etc...

extern Orbis2dTexture *icon0;
extern Orbis2dTexture *icon0;
etc...

Orbis2dTexture *icon0 = NULL;
Orbis2dTexture *icon0 = NULL;
etc...
```

for each value of `ICON_FILE_PATH`.

I mean to use :

```
for (int i=0; i<=5; i++ )
{
 #define ?????
 extern  ?????
 Orbis2dTexture ????
}
```

But I don't know how do...

Comment: `#define *char ICON_FILE_PATH"%s""ICON_FILE_PATH[i]"` that part makes no sense

Comment: Please explain the idea of `#define *char ICON_FILE_PATH"%s""ICON_FILE_PATH[i]"`

Comment: I wonder what this does in the middle of a function. ` extern Orbis2dTexture *icon[i];`

Comment: Please compile with warnings enabled.  Wow.  I mean I'm not quite sure how this compiled.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! I'd strongly recommend you read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask so your questions don't get downvoted. Ask specific questions instead of asking people to fix your code.

Comment: Be sure to edit your original question providing more information pointing out what the edits instead of treating the question as a conversation between you and the commentors, that way all the information is provided in the question itself.

Comment: You are mixing preprocessor directives and code as if both get compiled as-is (or possibly "interpreted on the fly"?). That is not the case. Read up on basic C syntax for `#define` and `extern` and compilation phases.

Comment: This is the rare case that I ask to describe the code instead of showing the code. Maybe if you describe in English what you want to achieve we might tell you how to write tha in C.

Comment: I have rewrite my question with better explanation on what I need to do. Hope that could help you to understand me. Please reopen my ask.

Answer (score 1):

If you want strings change `'`to `"`.

```
char *icon[6] = {"icon0","icon1","icon2","icon3","icon4","icon5"};
```

That sets up an array of pointers to `char`, initialised with the "readonly" pointers to string literals.
`'icon0'` is a (weird) multibyte character constant, not a multi character constant which could serve as a string.

The rest of the shown code is even more weird. I skip discussing it here.
Have a look at the comments.
Allow me to recommend starting with HelloWorlds and tutorials which provide you with known good code and then do little steps, always verified by testing, to upgrade the functionality of your program and your knowledge in parallel.

Comment: @JacekCz You are probably right. But it might help to get OP on the right track for what they are asking about.